# Extract e-mail from grouped objects

Tags: powershell

I have some code that pull user accounts from an OU in AD. I am sorting it using `Group-Object` so I know how many users are using the same email address.
Code below, the `$OuUser` uses `Get-ADUser` with Properties and Filter set to `*`.

```psh
$Duplicates = $OUUser | Select samaccountname, mail,UserPrincipalName |
              Group-Object Mail
```

I then have a `ForEach` loop to go through `$Duplicates`, putting the
data in to another variable for output.

What I am trying to achieve here is to output the information to CSV, so I can report on using Excel. I would like the group data to only have a E-Mail in it, rather then the expression data with `{}@=` characters in it.

```psh
$NewData = New-Object PSObject
ForEach ($x in $Duplicates) {
    IF ($x.Count -gt 1 ) {
        $NewData | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name($x.Name) -Force | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
        $NewData | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Count($x.Count) -Force | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
        $NewData | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Group($x.Group) -Force | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap

        $NewData
        #$Duplicates | Select Count, Name, Group 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second bit of code hurts my brain, but I *think* what you want is to output where multiple accounts use the same email address, grouped by email address. So, let's start with getting duplicates. Your first bit of code is kind of functional, but it really collects way more than you want it to. What you should do is pipe that command through a `Where` statement at the end when you are assigning `$Duplicates`, so that it actually only contains duplicates. This should do it for you:

```psh
$Duplicates = $OUUser | Select samaccountname, mail,UserPrincipalName |
              Group-Object Mail | Where{$_.Count -gt 1}
```

So, now you have just the duplicates in an array of grouping objects. What you want from there depends on how you want your CSV to be laid out. Let's do this the simple way and just have 1 line per email address with the email address, the number of accounts that use it, and those account names separated by semicolons.

```psh
$Duplicates | Select Name,Count,@{l='Accounts';e={($_.Group|Select -Expand samaccountname) -join ';'}} | ExportTo-CSV C:\Path\To\Duplicates.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

This will select the `Name` of the group (they were all grouped by email address, so that's the name), the `Count` of accounts in that group, and then adds a calculated property which takes the `Group` property for each group and expands the `samaccountname` property from that, then joins those account names with a semicolon. Your output would look something like this:

> "Name","Count","Accounts"
>   "jim.smith@company.com","2","Jim Smith;Jims Service Account"
>   "arcgroup@company.com","3","Action Reaction Creation DL;arcsrvcacct;arcReadOnly"

Comment: You are a The Mad Technician, yeah the second bit of code was over kill. I just couldn't figure out how to pipe the results in to a CSV without all the expression information. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Ran this on one Domain OU group good as gold, but on another I get the following error - Get-ADUser : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration c
ontext.
At C:\scripts\damianl\Get-DuplicateEmails-Logging.ps1:2 char:21
+ $OuUser = Get-AdUser <<<<  -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase 'ou=External,o
u=User Accounts,dc=bizdir,dc=nzpost,dc=co,dc=nz'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException... Is this because certain email field are empty or invalid entries?

Comment: That is an error with your Get-ADUser call. Without knowing what the actual line is, and the full error I can't really say. Perhaps you should open a new question with your issue since that really isn't related to this question.

Comment: I am using this $OuUser = Get-AdUser -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=external,ou=user accounts,dc=subdomain,dc=domain,dc=com"