# Error with Get-ADUser: Invalid enumeration context

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I posted this question the other day
[Extract e-mail from grouped objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856287/extract-e-mail-from-grouped-objects/30856711?noredirect=1#comment49758538_30856711)

```
$OuUser = @{}

$OuUser = Get-AdUser -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "domain"   

$Duplicates = $OuUser | Select samaccountname, mail,UserPrincipalName |
    Group-Object Mail | Where{$_.Count -gt 1}

$Duplicates | Select Name,Count,@{l='Accounts';e={($_.Group|Select -Expand samaccountname) -join ';'}} | 
    Export-CSV E:\Damo\Duplicates.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

The code works on one domain it works fine, testing it against a small set of users in a OU.

When testing on the domain I want to test against, which has a lot of users in it this code fails. The OU has email address in it which are not of an e-mail format. It points towards Get-ADUser for the error.

```
Get-ADUser : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration c
ontext.
At C:\scripts\CountEmailsDup.ps1:4 char:21
+ $OuUser = Get-AdUser <<<<  -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase 'ou=external,o
u=user accounts,dc=bizdir,dc=nzpost,dc=co,dc=nz' -SearchScope OneLevel
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The server has returned the following error: inv
   alid enumeration context.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.Ge
  tADUser
```

I am lost to why I am getting this error on one domain but not another.

Comment: How many users do you expect? This can happen enumerating too many users at once. You can try to use `-ResultPageSize 500` with `Get-ADUser`

Comment: There are over 900,000 account to process, i am trying to work with only the account with valid email address and find the duplicates then export to csv.

Comment: Well then I would try my first comment and see if it helps. Also does every one in the org have an email address? You could use a `-Filter` to get only the accounts with a valid email address to reduce the data set you are bringing back.

Comment: That makes sense, learning so much getting data from Active Directory. Thank you. I am now using -Filter { mail - like "*"} that should give me only accounts with email address. There are some email field with 123 and . in them, so  I will have to use length -gt 3 or something to skip them.

Comment: You can filter not only by `-like "*"` but also by `-like "....*"`, this should only return you those users which `mail` attribute is at least 4 symbols long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The biggest issue you have here is you are asking a lot from `Get-ADUser`. Based on your comment you are pulling in over 900,000 accounts. On top of that you are pulling all properties of those users. There is a touch of insanity there.

While I am not perfectly clear what your error means I do know that everyone that gets it is returning a lot of users which you clearly are. The first step to mitigate this is to use `-ResultPageSize` of `Get-ADUser`. Your mileage may vary but you need to experiment with number of records to return. 500-1000 is usually a good start.

I would never use `-Properties *` unless I was pulling for one user and wanted to see everything. I strongly doubt you are using all those properties in your function. Limit yourself to what you need for efficiency's sake. You would obviously need to specify `Mail`.

Since you are processing based on the `mail` property another thing would be to limit your results to those which only have a populated mail property. Couple of things you could do filters e.g "*", "....*"(from comments by Vesper) or "*@*" based on your comment of

> There are some email field with 123 and . in them, so I will have to use length -gt 3 or something to skip them.

Not sure about this and I don't have the sample data to test the theory but using the pipeline should also help things along instead of saving the results just to use them in the pipe anyway.

```psh
Get-AdUser -Properties mail -Filter 'mail -like "*@*"' -SearchBase "domain" -ResultPageSize 1000 | 
    Group-Object Mail | 
    Where{$_.Count -gt 1} |
    Select Name,Count,@{l='Accounts';e={($_.Group|Select -Expand samaccountname) -join ';'}} | 
    Export-CSV E:\Damo\Duplicates.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped narrow the data down using *@* and setting the properties to just mail, helped speed up the processing time.

Comment: Thanks for this.  There's also some great analysis here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32418.active-directory-troubleshooting-server-has-returned-the-following-error-invalid-enumeration-context.aspx.  From their output, a really simple solution may be to add a pipe to `SORT-OBJECT`, since that will ensure all data gets pulled from the pipeline before being passed on / you can just slip it in without adding a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but it put me on the right track and i though i'd add to the comments. The issue seems to be related to DCs and timeouts. Limiting query is helpful but not always an option. It also could be query is not that bad but DCs or infra is in bad shape (i am dealing with combo of both).
So to make it work.

- limiting results with filters (not where-object)
- finding best functional DC in the list and specifying it with -server.
- setting smaller result size actually helps keep timeouts down. I used resultsize of 100 and successfully. Anything over default would cause outlined error. I had scenarios where even smaller result size worked. It does seem to make things slower though but its better than failing.

Comment: Could you please provide actual code examples of you suggestions? That would clarify your answer a lot :)